# Смена значений слов на противоположное

Tags: значение-слов

Как так происходит, что некоторые слова со временем меняют смысл на противоположный? Например, известно, что раньше слово "победа" означало "поражение", а "наверное" - "точно". Из-за чего может так сильно измениться смысл, есть какое-то объяснение?

Comment: Откуда известно, что победа означала поражение?!

Comment: Разве Вы не знаете, что слова "легковерный" в словарях нет?

Comment: Куда понятнее будет пример УРОД и ЮРОД, с победой как-то вообще не понятно. Действительно, от куда данная информация про победу?

Answer (score 1):

В этом плане ещё показательнее чешский язык. Там и сегодня многие слова имеют противоположный так же звучащим русским словам смысл. Я не знаток чешского, но будучи в Праге не мог не заметить, что "черствый" означает "свежий", "позор" - "внимание", "воруе" - "предупреждает", "воняе" - "хорошо пахнет" ("вонявки" - это "духи" по чешски). "Овожи" - это "фрукты". Примеров много.

Answer (score 0):

Если хотя бы о влиянии церковно-славянского говорить, слов, изменивших смысл, десятки. До принятия Православия, к примеру, слова ***писать*** и ***читать*** имели другие значения: ***рисовать*** и ***произносить***; ***честный***, по-русски — *правдивый*, в ЦСЯ исконно значит ***удостоенный чести и славы***, а *начальник* — ***дарователь начала***; русское позитивное ***прелесть*** в ЦСЯ — атрибут дьявольский. С этим последним связан целый отряд слов, с лёгкой руки реформаторов поменявших приставку ***без-*** на ***бес-***, и слова на письме превратились в вызывающий у многих отторжение (***бес-полезный*** вместо ***без-полезный***) неподдающийся разумному толкованию ёрнический материал.

Относительно победы: смысл слова — в корне *бе*(*хъ*), и чешские *anbite*, *nezbitny* это объясняют, «тот, которого нельзя бить», т.е., «кто не побит».

Answer (score 0):

Я на такой вопрос ответа не имею . Но , со своей стороны , предлагаю сопоставить по смыслу слова украiнской мовы с однозвучными русскими словами . Вот , подобрал навскидку несколько , в скобках перевод с украинского на русский : КРАЩЕ (=лучше) , БОГАТО (=много) , ГАДАТИ (=думать) , ДИВИТИСЯ (=смотреть) , ЧУЄШ (=слышишь) , ДОБРЕ (=хорошо) , ПОГАНИЙ (=плохой) ,  ШТУЧНИЙ (=искусственный) ,  МЕШКАТИ (=жить) ,   ГОРИЩЕ (=чердак) , ПАЛИТИ (=курить) , ПИТАННЯ (=вопрос) .

Answer (score 0):

Примеры ваши неудачны. "Наверное" и сейчас может означать "точно", в нем корень "вер" - от верить. Так что "наверное" (очень упрощенно) - то, что можно на веру. Для кого-то вера - это точно, для кого-то недостоверно.  Отсюда и разница в значениях.

С победой - весьма сомнительно, что именно такое значение ("поражение") у этого слова было. Но если и было, то тоже ничего удивительного. Там корень "бѣд" (беда)...

Ну а в общем такая ситуация (смена значения на антонимичное) в языке встречается достаточно часто. Причину каждый раз надо смотреть конкретно, а часто её и нет вовсе. Божьим промыслом, что называется. А среди причин иррациональных - табуирование названия (что-то неприятное, страшное могли назвать добрым словом и наоборот, чтобы не сглазить и не накликать, а потом прижилось). Или, например, иронически назвать кого-то или что-то. Как последнего нищего - князем.